# Web page does not load after validation

Tags: javascript, html

I have an issue where I log onto a site and try to look at a "Document Library"  typing in the username and password it will hang.

If i press the refresh button it will load. I have to know what is causing this to hang like that when I bring up the project in Visual Studios 2013 and test it. it works fine.

When I inspect element on the hang it says this in console "HTML1300 Navigation occured. and under it File:Index" and I click that index and it goes to debugger tab and says Failed to open "web URL"

The second thing in the console is what looks like a warning. HTML 1527: DOCTYPE expected. Consider adding a valid HTML5 doctype:  this is hte code for that page

```
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
      <head><title>

      CMMS - Document Library

       </title><link type="text/css" href="/Content/themes/redmond/jquery-
       ui-1.8.17.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/content/dynatree/ui.dynatree.css" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/content/site.css" />
<script src="/content/js/jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/content/dynatree/jquery.dynatree.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/content/js/jquery.ui.dialog.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/content/js/jquery.form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/content/js/jquery.blockUI.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/content/js/jquery.sb.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/content/js/jquery.ui.accordion.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="/content/themes/redmond/jquery.sb.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
<script src="/content/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/content/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/content/js/jquery.contextMenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/content/js/jquery.tapandhold.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/js/pca.core.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="/content/themes/redmond/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="Stylesheet" /><link type="text/css" href="/content/themes/redmond/jquery.contextMenu.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("button").button();
        $(".button").button().click(function (event) {
            //event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

but once the refresh button is pressed everything works. i dont know why. and works fine on localhost when running project

Comment: Also, consider reading the [how to ask question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page

Comment: What about the server side code?

Comment: its all written on server side. i got more code ie. authentication  functions but all looks fine i put a break point on the line that returns the page after authenication (Return Redirect(redirectURL))  but looks ok to me.

Comment: maybe in the code that generate the page under _redirectURL_